# Throw exception when Content-Type is not specified

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API project that returns some product data.

If no Accept header is specified it returns XML as default, done like so in my `WebApiConfig`:

```
config.Formatters.Clear();
config.Formatters.Add(new XmlMediaTypeFormatter());
config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
config.Formatters.Add(new FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter());
```

So default is XML, the first formatter, but the API still supports JSON if the request asks for it.

In my `ControllerHelper`, I added a **415 Format not supported** response:

```
catch (FormatException) 
{
    var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType) 
    {
        Content = new StringContent(string.Format(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType.ToString())),
    };
    throw new HttpResponseException(resp);
}
```

And I would like to throw that response if no Accept header is specified and therefore require it to be set, either to `application/xml`, `text/xml` or `application/json`.

For example, if I test to set accept in Advanced Rest Client to `application/foo` I want to throw an exception.

---

[image]

---

How to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you have a look at request.Headers ?

Comment: I may have stumbled across it in my search for an answer.. should you specify it for each ActionResult in the controller(s) or what is the best approach? Thanks.

Comment: Try filters in web apis. There you can parse your header and get the content type and returns the exception/error message or watever back to the client. Filters applies to all Actions. Do not have much experience through, but seen it working.

Comment: Neither do I @theinsaneone, feels like I'm tumbling on thin ice here! Thanks for the response. I will update if any progress or similar.

Comment: You can google about action filters in web api. It will be the right approach for you problem

Comment: Thanks @theinsaneone for your response. With your and Alex Art help I managed to solve the issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class NotAcceptableConnegHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private const string allMediaTypesRange = "*/*";

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var acceptHeader = request.Headers.Accept;
        if (!acceptHeader.Any(x => x.MediaType == allMediaTypesRange))
        {
            var hasFormetterForRequestedMediaType = GlobalConfiguration
                .Configuration
                .Formatters
                .Any(formatter => acceptHeader.Any(mediaType => formatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Contains(mediaType)));

            if (!hasFormetterForRequestedMediaType)
                return Task<HttpResponseMessage>.Factory.StartNew(() => new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable));
        }
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

In your WebApiConfig file:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.MessageHandlers.Add(new NotAcceptableConnegHandler());
}
```

The code is from: http://pedroreys.com/2012/02/17/extending-asp-net-web-api-content-negotiation/

Comment: Thanks for the useful link. I will check it out!

Comment: This worked out for me. I created a `MethodOverrideHandler` with the following code and changed the `allMediaTypesRange` to my content-type specification and ResponseMessage to `UnsupportedMediaType` and it worked! THANKS :D